# How to write a Gompertz model as an accelerated failure time model?

Tags: distributions, survival, model, accelerated-failure-time

Accelerated failure time models are usually defined as a model for $X>0$ with (constants) covariates $Z\in \mathbb{R}^p$ such that

\begin{equation}
\log(X) = \mu + \beta^*Z + \sigma W,
\end{equation}
where $W$ is a random variable. The usual AFT models are Weibull, Loglogistic and Lognormal*. I am trying to implement Gompertz as an AFT model to get a model with exponential hazards, and since my data is atypically censored and truncated, I have given up trying to find an R package and just doing it myself. Some `R` packages have an implementation of AFT models that are Gompertz distributed, but reading the documentation and code; I have not been able to figure out what distribution $W$ needs to have.

I'm pretty sure that the Gompertz model is not exactly in the same form as above but on the form
\begin{equation} 
\log(X) = \mu + \beta^*Z + W\end{equation}
where $W$ is a distribution depending on a parameter $\sigma$ but not in the usual scaling way. Whether or not this is an AFT model seems to be up to definition (or taste), but it still has the interpretation of a proportional median survival time model (and all other quantiles), which is what I am interested in. I hope someone can help me, and it would be perfect if someone had a reference for an answer.

*See e.g. Survival analysis, techniques for censored and truncated data, John P. Klein & Melvin L. Moeschberger 2003 second edition, Science+Business Media, Inc series: Statistics for Biology and Health Springer.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can fit a parametric Gompertz regression model, it won't have a simple interpretation in terms of the proportional survival quantiles that AFT models provide. That type of interpretation depends on the form of $\sigma W$ being independent of the covariate values, with (1) effects of all of the covariate values incorporated into $\beta^* Z$ and (2) $\beta^* Z$ being linearly related to $\log X$. Once you make $\sigma W$ depend on covariate values (as seems implicit in your question), that simple interpretation in terms of acceleration of time goes away.

The Gompertz model does have a proportional hazards interpretation. Among parametric survival families, only the Weibull distribution is closed under both proportional-hazards and accelerated-failure-time models. The Gompertz model can be thought of as a *log-Weibull* distribution, with the log-hazard *linear* in $X$ rather than in $\log X$ as for the Weibull. See the [Rodríguez course notes](https://grodri.github.io/survival/ParametricSurvival.pdf).